# Can I create local branches in Git without creating remote branches when I merge to remote?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I don't believe this is the right way to use Git but it's what I've been told to do: Don't create new remote branches! I might ask a separate question on Workplace.SE about trying to get him to use Git better.

I'm working in an Agile environment and I'm used to creating a new branch for each story. My boss only wants one branch for each epic (split into Dev, UAT and Live).

How can I keep my local environment clean while complying with his wishes? I've looked at `git rebase` but I'm not sure that will do it or that it won't have side-effects.

So, to recap, I'm trying to create local branches without creating remote branches when I merge.

Comment: It's very well possible, I do it often. A total ban on new branches sounds overly protective to me, a new branch would be a good way to get new stuff checked out by colleagues before merging it.  They're deleted easily.  But perhaps the PHB has reasons to not want new branches.  `git rebase` is often used to update branches with commits from the master branch, but has other uses.  Its man page explains it pretty well, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible with Git!

It sounds like the best thing to do would be to create the branch locally and then merge it back in before pushing. So you'd push the epic branch only once you'd merged your local feature branch into it.

A workflow might look like this:

```
1. git pull my-epic
2. git checkout -b my-local-working-branch
3. Make awesome code changes, including commits.
4. git checkout my-epic
5. git pull
6. git merge my-local-working-branch
7. git branch -d my-local-working-branch
8. git push
```

Do you think that (or something like it) would work?

Comment: It's been a couple of years since I've used Git so I've forgotten some of the finer details. Won't merging create my branch remotely to keep the history intact?

Comment: Nope! It'll only be created remotely if you push it. However, just to be safe, I added a step (7) to delete the branch before you ever push.